# Salvar form Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Como posso fazer para meu formuláio não fazer sumbit do mesmo formulário varias vezes.
Estou com este problema pois alguns usuários estão clicando em salvar varias vezes, não esperando a tela atualizar, assim então, está salvando varios registros duplicados.

Encontrei algumas validações  JQuery mas nenhuma até o momento ajudou 100%.
1º Tentei desabilitar o botão quando clicar em salvar, porém parou de funcionar no caso
do existir um campo obrigatório não consegui mais validar pra habilitar o botão Salvar novamente.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devillers/fr7gmbcy/)

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    $(this).find('button[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
    return true; // return false stops the from from actually submitting.. this is only for demo purposes
});
```

Não sei qual a melhor solução para esse problema...

Comment: Nos meus códigos eu desabilito o botão e habilito novamente no retorno da requisição.

Comment: Como eu faria pra obter o retorno?

Comment: precisa de todo código da requisição ajax que vc está fazendo para ver como ficaria

Comment: Pior que eu não faço a requisição ajax. Eu estou usando o Html.BeginForm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Olha existem varias formas de tratar isso, eu recomendaria que seja feita uma função em jquery que Limpe o seu formulário ao clicar no botão de salvar, mas isso seria eficiente se a validação do seu formulário for feita toda do lado cliente.

Outra solução é usar um plugin jquery que faça isso, como este link aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830542/prevent-double-submission-of-forms-in-jquery